# Can I make the output of a lambda function depend on conditionals without declaring a function to handle it?

Tags: python, lambda, list-comprehension

I've been going through the Python tutorial on docs.python.org, and I just learned I could generate a list containing squared numbers by doing

```
lista1 = list(map(lambda x: x**2, range(19)))
```

While trying this out I thought of writing something similar that would fill the list with x -> x when x is even, and with x -> x**3 when x is odd. I wanted to do it using lambda functions again, so I tried

```
lista1 = list(map(lambda x:
              if x % 2 == 0:
              x
              else:
              x***3, range(19)))
```

I found out that sadly this isn't valid Python syntax. I know I could do this instead and it works because I tried:

```
def funcx(x):
if x % 2 == 0:
    return x
else:
    return x**3

lista4 = list(map(lambda x: funcx(x), range(19)))
```

But I was wondering if I can do it without defining funcx(x), just using lambda functions.

Thank you!

Comment: Try out `[x if x % 2 == 0 else x**3 for x in range(19)]`

Answer (score 3):

A lambda must be an *expression* that can be evaluated. They cannot contain any statement.

Luckily, Python has a ternary operator that allows you to express the "lambda" in your second snippet as

```
lambda x: (x) if (x % 2 == 0) else (x**3)
```

(The parenthesis here are in fact unnecessary, but are included to make the syntax at play more clear.)

However, in this case, lambda's and `map` are not the most appropriate tool for the job. A better (more efficient) solution would make use of a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
lista4 = [(x if x % 2 == 0 else x**3) for x in range(19)]
```

Using this approach, we save the overhead of repetitive function calls and convey our intent much more clearly.

---

As a side note, the lambda in your second code snippet is superfluous. The expression `lambda x: func(x)` can be replaced by simply `func`. For instance,

```
map(lambda x: funcx(x), range(19))
```

is the same as

```
map(funcx, range(19))
```

only with added overhead and obscurity.